# I have a postgres database table with a timestamp with timezone column. How do i query and get the values properly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest

When i query the db from my rest application ,the returned results are different from the ones that i get while im in pgadmin.
The time is off by 2 hours as thats the timezone im in

Comment: First is the field `timestamp` or `timestamptz`? What is the `TimeZone` setting for the server? The database is at another location from where you are running the pgAdmin client correct? If so what is the timezone where you are running the pgAdmin client?

Comment: Im running the database locally . My timezone is utc +2 but the results  are just utc

Comment: You need to answer the rest of the questions and include those answers in your original question to get a meaningful response.

Comment: You need to post actual (or sample data), the actual query used on that data, and the results. All as text - **no images**. Further, what do you get running same query from command line (psql). It is possible pgAdmin settings may effect the result as well. Your statement "timezone is utc +2 but the results are just utc" does seems to be contrary to how Postgres operates.